Floor of eigenvectors times a big constant modulo a prime - Is it known to create a uniform distribution?
Is there some kind of result that would show that this operation is indistinguishable from a uniform distribution over $\mathbb Z_p$? Take some matrix like $M^i_j := i\ \times\ j$ and compute its eigenvectors. Now, for each entry $e^i_j$, meaning the projection onto the $j$th coordinate of the $i$th eigenvector, sorted in whichever way, set $\mu^i_j := \lfloor 10^{99} e^i_j\rfloor \pmod p$, where $10^{99}$ constant is chosen so that each $e^i_j$ gets sent to some integer value much larger than $p$, maybe around the size $p^2$ or larger. My question is whether it is known for a fact, or used as a cryptographic assumption perhaps, that the $\mu^i_j$ follow a uniform distribution of some kind, perhaps $\text{Uniform}(0,\cdots,p-1)$? From my initial testing it doesn't appear that how you define $M^i_j$ really matters, so long as the constant is chosen to be large enough to actually split the entry "randomly" along modulo $p$. For example if you set the constant too small you end up with too many 0's to pretend to be uniform.  Is this kind of operation studied at all, does it have any kind of merit? The context which I was using it was to generate curves which are shortest paths on shuffled rows of $\mu$ from (0,0) to (n,n) where $M$ was an $n \times n$ matrix. So that taking a 0 incurs no penalty, but taking $p-1$ incurs the largest possible penalty of $p-1$.  It is essentially a stochastic program that computes a kind of curve which may be used in other applications. Clearly the curve comes from some kind of non-uniform distribution, more like a random walk with drift, but perhaps you get an equivalent distribution of curves from just taking a random matrix with the same probability of having a zero entry? Perhaps this is related to discrete logarithm in some way, so long as the constants are large enough? Or maybe it is known for a fact this distribution is indistinguishable from uniform as the constants increase in size? Thank you for any insight into this.
We should assume that $M$ has $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors for this to make any sense. So I suppose I am asking about the distribution of the eigenvectors mod $p$ when you multiple the eigenvectors by a big enough number to make the modulo $p$ spread out, and chop off the rest of the irrelevant digits. Thanks
